# TypeError: Cannot set property "name" of null to "Last Name, First Name"

Tags: javascript, properties, null

Getting this error on return from call to database script.  Trying to load two database items returned in searchList into a name/value pair local list variable.  (some private data/names redacted).  Here is the script:

```
tw.local.myList = new tw.object.listOf.NameValuePair();
    if(tw.local.searchList.listLength != null)
{
for(var i=0; i<tw.local.searchList.listLength; i++){
    tw.local.myList[i].name = tw.local.searchList[i].LastName + ", " + tw.local.searchList[i].FirstName;
    tw.local.myList[i].value = tw.local.searchList[i].EID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Trivial reproduction: `null.name = "Ooops"`. Find out why the value (of `tw.local.myList[i]`) was null when it wasn't expected; fix it.

Comment: The test `if(tw.local.searchList.listLength != null)` is redundant since if that returns false, then the for loop won't run anyway as `0 < null` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers, user2864740, 
I was missing the apples from the apple pie. Have to initialize the list:
 tw.local.myList.insertIntoList(i, new tw.object.NameValuePair());